# How to interpret a WKB (Well-known-binary)?

Tags: postgis, well-known-binary

I read this example of a WKB (well know binary) from "PostGIS in Action" 2ed.:

```
SELECT ST_AsBinary(
ST_GeomFromWKB(
  E'\\001\\001\\000\\000\\000\\321\\256B\\312O\\304Q\\300\\347\\030\\220\\275\\336%E@',
  4326
  )
);
```

I understand the `E'..'` is an escape string, and the escaped backslash is a separator. But I don't understand the rest of the well-known binary.

Can anyone explain what are the numbers and letters?

They do not look like hexidecimal according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Well-known_binary) consider e.g. `304Q`. Also the `336%E@` looks weird.

Comment: This question is a follow-up to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34823158/whats-the-e-before-a-postgres-string

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`ST_GeomFromWKB()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromWKB.html) takes the a [WKB](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#OpenGISWKBWKT) as input data type [`bytea`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html).

Not sure why your example uses the old escape string syntax for the string literal. Maybe because the [examples in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html) still do so, too.

(The manual has eventually been **updated**. Postgres 9.3 or later show modern notation.)

It's not wrong, just needlessly noisy. Unless you are running a very old Postgres instance with the setting `standard_conforming_strings = off`, you can replace it with the modern, standard form:

```
SELECT ST_AsBinary(ST_GeomFromWKB('\001\001\000\000\000\321\256B\312O\304Q\300\347\030\220\275\336%E@', 4326));
```

The above is the [escape format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html#AEN5675) for a `bytea` literal. [The manual advises:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html#AEN5675)

> ... this format should probably be avoided for most new applications.

So, double "old-school" syntax. Alternatively, you can use the shorter [hex format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html#AEN5666):

```
SELECT ST_AsBinary(ST_GeomFromWKB('\x0101000000d1ae42ca4fc451c0e71890bdde254540', 4326));
```

Related:

- [Insert varchar with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

Answer (score 2):

It's a type of binary encoding, which can be converted using [encode and decode functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-binarystring.html). There are several binary encodings, such as base64, hex, and escape (default). Most folks that show WKB as hex-encoded text, which uses digits 0-9 and characters A-F (upper or lower case).

Here is a demo, where all of the outputs are text:

```
SELECT
  encode(b, 'base64') AS encode_base64,
  encode(b, 'escape') AS encode_escape,
  encode(b, 'hex') AS encode_hex,
  ST_AsEWKT(encode(b, 'hex')::geometry)
FROM (
  SELECT '\001\001\000\000\000\321\256B\312O\304Q\300\347\030\220\275\336%E@'::bytea AS b
) d;

-[ RECORD 1 ]-+-------------------------------------------------------------------
encode_base64 | AQEAAADRrkLKT8RRwOcYkL3eJUVA
encode_escape | \x01\x01\000\000\000\321\256B\312O\304Q\300\347\x18\220\275\336%E@
encode_hex    | 0101000000d1ae42ca4fc451c0e71890bdde254540
st_asewkt     | POINT(-71.06737 42.29586)
```